# Winter 17 broke anchor links

Tags: community, lightning-aura-components, winter17

I have a Lightning Component used in our community using the napili templates in our prod and sandbox environment with identical code that uses anchor tags to jump to headers within the component. Today, while testing something in our sandbox, I found that the anchor links now cause the whole page to reload before jumping to the correct header. Wondering if I had missed something, I checked out our prod environment only to find that it doesn't reload the page when jumping to the header. The only difference between the environments is Winter 17 in our sandbox.

I know that [the documentation says to avoid using the hash (#)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_supported_html_tags.htm?search_text=anchor) but it hasn't been an issue until this recent update.

Is there any indication of what changed in the newest release to cause this issue? Along with that, is there a workaround that works with this release to get this simple functionality back?

Comment: What is the container application that you are using the component in - e.g. one.app (Salesforce1/Lightning Experience), Visualforce, Canvas, your own custom .app?

Comment: It's in the community using napili templates. I'll update the question.

Comment: any update on this @MatthewGreen

Comment: @cartman nope, I've just rewritten the component to no longer use the anchor tags anymore. Not ideal but better than a full reload of the page.